# How to start the animation for each active slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, bootstrap-4, gsap

The code for the animation  using "gsap" is the following code

```
$('polygon').each(function() {
            var minY = -600;
            var maxY = 0;
            var minX = -600;
            var maxX = 600;
            var randomY = Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxY - minY + 1)) + minY;
            var randomX = Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxX - minX + 1)) + minX;
            var tl = new TimelineLite();
            tl
            .set(this, {
                transformOrigin: "50% 50%",
                position: "absolute",
                x: randomX,
                y: randomY,
                rotation: randomX,
                scale: 1
            })
            .to(this, 3, {
                x: 0,
                y: 0,
                rotation: 0,
                scale: 1
            }, 0.5);
        });
```

The animation is made in the bootstrap 4 sliders. Animation works only on the first slide. How to start the animation with each slide change

Comment: Please include all relevant code, and even better create a working snippet that demonstrates the problem

Comment: I decided to thank the problem!

Comment: eerrr what? You are thanking the problem?